# I accidentally did ssh-add -d .. how do I re-add my key from authorized_keys?

Tags: ssh

I accidentally did `ssh-add -d`, trying to remove a certain key but it removed all of them from my ssh-agent. Do I need to re-add my key from authorized_keys or will it automatically happen next time I login with `ssh -i me@wherever`?

I'm afraid to logout and then be locked out of the system.

I tried typing `ssh-add /home/me/.ssh/authorized_keys` but then it asks for a passphrase and I don't know what passphrase it's talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ssh-add` is the client part of `ssh-agent`, it has nothing to do with granting access to hosts (which is done by adding the public key (`.pub`) to `~/.ssh/authorized_hosts` on the *server* side). `ssh-agent` is a program which you use on the client side, the server side only needs `sshd`.

By invoking `ssh-add -d`, you have cleared a *cached key* from `ssh-agent` such that you have to re-enter your SSH keyfile passphrase next time you ssh to a system. **You won't lock yourself out by clearing this cache**. Simply run `ssh-add` (or `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` for a specific keyfile) to remember the keyfile passphrase again for this session.

The `-i` option of `ssh` is only necessary if your private key is located on a non-standard location. `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@host` is nearly equivalent to `ssh user@host` since `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is one of the standard places where SSH looks for a keyfile.

The reason why `ssh-add ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` prompts for a password is because it did not recognize an unprotected key, and thus assumed a password-protected key. In fact, the file has an invalid format so no password will work here.

See also the manual page `ssh-add(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either copy the contents of `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (which is your public key) and add it to the end of `.ssh/authorized_keys` or use `ssh-copy-id localhost` to let SSH do the copying.

Note that *your* key doesn't need to be in `.ssh/authorized_keys` unless you plan on SSH'ing into that computer using that key.